# Windows won't boot - Laptop always boot to clonezilla live without any usb/cd/external devices

Tags: clonezilla

I downloaded and burned (save .iso file) Clonezilla to an usb using Tuxboot.

After that I restart my laptop and now my laptop always boot to clonezilla live (not windows 7). I've already removed all usb, external devices... from the laptop but it still boot to Clonezilla live.

What happened and How do I fix this and boot to windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem and I am able to boot to my windows 7 now.
I basically follow this instruction after googled: "repair windows 7 boot" => http://www.tomshardware.com/news/win7-windows-7-mbr,100... the command "bootrec.exe /FixBoot" works for me.

So I check my local hard C drive (I only have one drive) and I see somehow the .iso file has been unzipped into the C drive, so all of the files/folders you see on the USB when you create Clonezilla USB boot are also presenting in the C drive now.

I'll go ahead and remove all of them.

Thanks guy for your supports.